# Authenticate a user in Laravel with Passport access_token credentials

Tags: laravel-passport, laravel-5.8, laravel-authentication

So, I have a site running on Laravel 5.8 that serves an API for client auth, let's call this 'core'.  I have another laravel site of the same version with no database implementation, let's call this 'app'.  It connects to the core via Passport and everything is working great, from registering a client to logging in and out.  I have followed Laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport) for this.

While this is working for all '/api' routes.   How can I use this authentication for 'web' middleware routes?  I need to be able to create a session for 'web' based on the 'api' credentials and be able to authenticate the user from that.

I have read about Laravel's Guard but haven't really dig into it, is this the right way?